# Application with Output similar to the GUI output of "WireShark"

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, networking, command-line, software-recommendation

I know that WireShark allows live packet capturing as well as details being displayable in the GUI.  Is there any similar program that operates on a CLI, rather than a GUI?  This is intended for use on a server install, in which only CLI is available (and also where disk space is limited, so much that the dependencies for the `wireshark` packages cannot be installed (i.e. the packages for the GUI).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, [`tshark`](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)  (text shark) is the same program, but with a noninteractive command line interface.

You can also run tshark on the server and transfer the captures over ssh to a wireshark gui running somewhere else.

For example:

```
  mbp@joy% sudo tshark -i wlan0 -p  -R 'http'
  Capturing on wlan0
  3.929359 192.168.178.22 -> 66.102.11.104 HTTP GET / HTTP/1.1 
  4.104763 66.102.11.104 -> 192.168.178.22 HTTP HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently  (text/html)
  4.118925 192.168.178.22 -> 66.102.11.104 HTTP GET / HTTP/1.1 
  4.295749 66.102.11.104 -> 192.168.178.22 HTTP HTTP/1.1 302 Found  (text/html)
  4.355713 192.168.178.22 -> 66.102.11.104 HTTP GET / HTTP/1.1 
  4.560568 66.102.11.104 -> 192.168.178.22 HTTP HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/html)
  4.588767 192.168.178.22 -> 66.102.11.104 HTTP GET /images/nav_logo40.png HTTP/1.1
```

You can also do `tshark ... |tee packetlog` so it goes both to the screen and to the file.

Or, alternatively, `tshark -w stuff.pcap` will write the raw packets into that file, which you can then copy to another machine and open within the wireshark gui, if you want to do more in-depth investigation.

Comment: Could I also do something like `sudo tshark -i wlan0 -p -R 'http' > packetlogs.txt` or something similar in terminal, so that it logs everything to a file, and perhaps run this command in a `screen` session or something?  I'd hate to do a `tcpdump`, because that would be a PITA after a while.

Comment: FOR THE RECORD... I tested `tshark` for about an hour, and compared the output with the output from wireshark.  It shows exactly what I need (the complete packet analysis) in `tshark`'s output, esp. in the file i had the output go to.  Works for me now, it'll be an awesome CLI alternative to wireshark in this manner :)

Answer (score 1):

[tshark](http://packages.ubuntu.com/tshark) [image: Install tshark]
is a good option.

An alternative is [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) [image: Install tcpdump],
which is a well-known predecessor.  It's widely available on other platforms, so you might run into it even if you don't use it on your server.

Comment: yeah, i have issues with tcpdump (basically with it being a PITA because it just doesnt like to work well on my system :/)

Comment: @EvilP Then tshark might be the way to go.  I use tcpdump primarily on systems where it's available and wireshark/tshark isn't. I usually end up pulling the captures back into the wireshark GUI, anyway.